# Why MonitoredTrainingSession can not receive graph as an argument?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Why `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession` does not receive graph as an argument?

`tf.Session` (and `tf.train.Supervisor`) can do that as below:

```py
with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
    # Build computation graph...

with tf.Session(graph=g) as sess:
    # Run operations...
```

Only the way of writing as below is recommended?

```py
with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
    # Build computation graph...

    with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(...) as mon_sess:
        # Run operations...
```

Comment: The latter example looks neat because it's clear that `g` is in its `with` scope.

Comment: That looks correct; Scaffold [explicitly uses the default Graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py#L207). Do you have a concrete use-case for passing the graph through explicitly? If so, feel free to open a pull request (or a feature request) on Github.